# Strange sentence construction: を今

Tags: translation, particle-を

So, I'm back again with another translation help, from a line in the song "Yoake to Hotaru"

夏が来ないままの街**を今**

I've known, naturally as a basic, that を functions as an object marker for a verb. However, it seems here that the thing that takes a direct object is 今. Might there be some function of it I still do not know? Or perhaps, it concerns syntax and grammar more, if anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the verb being omitted. 今 is modifying the time of the sentence overall. Looking at the nearby lines, it's not entirely clear what the verb is. Here are some things it could be:

- 夏がこないままの街**を**行く
- 夏がこないままの街**を**歩く
- 夏がこないままの街**を**藍の色**が**染め上げる

Other things are naturally potentially possible as well.